# What happens when I Clean a Project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse's project clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/eclipses-project-clean)

This might be a foolish question but any way, what happen when clean a project in Eclipse? Do eclipse erase my files and re write them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generated/built .class files are deleted and the source is compiled again.

Comment: source is compiled again if build automatically is on