# Android Application icon not changing on phone despite reboot, uninstall and re-install

Tags: android, eclipse, icons

## Solved

Thanks to @Ifor's suggestion I think I have discovered what was causing it. Since I was not making any changes to the code, only to the resources eclipse must have not bothered creating a new .apk.
  Deliberately breaking the code meant that I was changing the code therefore prompting eclipse to re-create the apk. I could be wrong in my hypothesis being a bit of a newbie but it's fixed now anyway so thanks everybody!

I have two home-made applications both with icon A. Recently I got sick of being confused by them so I tried to change one of them for a new icon, icon B.
This is not working!
I have tried:
Re-installing the app;
Un-installing the app then re-installing it.
Un-installing the app then rebooting the phone and the computer then re-installing the app.
None of this works, I still end up with the original Icon A.
I have replaced the icons in the hdpi, ldpi and mdpi folders. I've also searched the folder containing my application for .png files, the only ones there are the three versions of Icon B (the correct one)
What's happening, is there a cache problem like with the windows phone development? I came across this while searching for an answer.
Btw I'm using Eclipse on Windows Vista Ultimate
Any Ideas Anyone?

As Requested here's the Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.PianoSets" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".PianoSets" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SavedAccounts"></activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml file? Also, the name of your icon resource too may be of help.

Comment: Are you sure any changes are getting though, diliberately break the code, e.g. make it do a null popinter exception.

Comment: useful suggestion @Ifor, I broke the code, it threw an error. However NOW since 'fixing' the code it installed correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Ifor's suggestion I think I have discovered what was causing it. Since I was not making any changes to the code, only to the resources eclipse must have not bothered creating a new .apk.
Deliberately breaking the code meant that I was changing the code therefore prompting eclipse to re-create the apk. I could be wrong in my hypothesis being a bit of a newbie but it's fixed now anyway so thanks everybody!

Answer (score 9):

A 'cleaner' method (pardon the pun!) that worked for me (forcing an update of replaced ic_launcher icon):

```
Project -> Clean
```

I got the idea from this tutorial:

http://www.slideshare.net/YasmineSherif91/android-application-how-to-change-the-icon-tutorial-2

EDIT:  Although `clean` updates the icons, I get build errors unless I do a `Refresh` on the added resources before doing the `clean`.  More info about the complementary function of `refresh` and `clean`:

[Does refreshing in Eclipse also Clean the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415076/does-refreshing-in-eclipse-also-clean-the-project?rq=1)

Some cautions and limitations of `clean` here:

[Function of Project > Clean in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse)

Comment: In my opinion, doing a clean with each build (easier when you have auto-build turned off in Eclipse) is a good practice to use in avoiding caching issues with regard to your compiled code. When in doubt, clear every cache you can think of! :)

Comment: Other solution is to use different name of icon. Example: ic_launcher2.png or ic_launcher3.png or so on.

Answer (score 2):

I find deleting the gen directory fixes this sort of problem easily.  It gets rebuilt immediately, and the rebuild refreshes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file you use to replace the old ones are also in lower caps. Ie, replacing home.png with Home.png will not work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You probably updated icon in only one folder. Make sure you've updated the icon in all "drawable" folders:

```
res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
```