# Does refreshing in Eclipse also Clean the project?

Tags: eclipse

I hope the question isn't too vague but I was wondering if running 'Refresh' also calls 'Clean'.

Does running 'Clean' run 'Refresh' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, it does not. Refresh reloads the last version of your project's files (like, if you modified something outside of eclipse, you need to refresh in eclipse to have the new modif show up). Clean on the other hand deletes all the compiled files and recompiles your project's sources

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. Eclipse reads the files from the file system and buffers them. Refresh only tells eclipse to reread the files.