# eclipse not updating android project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm having trouble making eclipse update the default icons and app name. I have changed the icons in the res/drawable-[h][m][l] folders and changed the 'app_name' in the manifest file but i still see the old icon and name when i test on my device.

I made the application with phonegap, if it matters, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to clean and rebuild your project. Do that by going to `Project -> Clean` and then rebuild your project.

Comment: What does 'clean' do? It seems to fix many things in Android.

Comment: This is good question and I found this answer on StackOverflow: [Function of project clean in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

A clean and rebuild should fix this issue. If not, a fresh restart of Eclipse should do the trick.

Comment: What an absolute joke of an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you replaced the original files through OS's file manager instead of drag & dropping it into  Eclipse, you have to select the /res directory and press F5 to tell Eclipse to refresh, otherwise it will hold onto old resource files.