# Could not execute this Akka actor based test code

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am new to Scala Akka actor. Based on the akka tutorial example on their website,i coded a similar example with just printing messages with the time they started. But the code does not get executed in my eclipse IDE.

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object AkaObj extends App{


process()

sealed trait PiMessage
case class Work(value:String) extends PiMessage
case class printComp(valu:String)extends PiMessage
case object Start extends PiMessage 
case class ListObj(cont:Seq[String]) extends PiMessage


class Worker extends Actor{

  def receive()={

    case Work(value:String)=>
      println(value)
      sender ! printComp(value)
  }
}

class Master(listener: ActorRef) extends Actor{

  val nrOfWorkers = 10
  var counter = 0
  var lis = ListBuffer[String]()

  val workerRouter = context.actorOf(
  Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

  def receive()={
    //handle message
    case Start=>workerRouter ! Work("Start now " + System.currentTimeMillis())
    case printComp(value:String)=> { 
      counter+=1
      lis.append(counter+"-"+value)
      if(counter >=10)
          listener ! ListObj(lis.toSeq)

      // Stops this actor and all its supervised children
      context.stop(self)
      }
  }
 }

class Listener extends Actor{

  def receive()={

    case ListObj(cont:Seq[String])=>
      println("Completed " +cont)
      context.system.shutdown()
  }
}

def process(){
  // Create an Akka system
    val system = ActorSystem("PiSystem")

  // create the result listener, which will print the result and shutdown the system
    val listener = system.actorOf(Props[Listener], name = "listener")

  // create the master
    val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(listener)),
      name = "master")

  // start the calculation
    master ! Start
}

}
```

Issue: The error message i get is: "Error: Could not find or load main class AkaObj"
It does not even compiling i think. When i run the project,that's the message i get.

Comment: You need to be a little more explicit about what issue(s) you are having.  It's kind of vague based on your description.

Comment: I have updated the question. I could not run the project.

Comment: I would recommend that you start with one of the getting started tutorials in Activator: http://akka.io/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I managed to run your code just after dependencies were resolved. So the problem is in your environment configuration. I use Intellij Idea IDE.

Try this [Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334625/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: I tested the code in Scala cmd in Windows. Still i get the same error. So i think the issue could not be with Eclipse or the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is the use of `object AkaObj extends App`. When programming scala I have noticed that using **scala.App** is restricted to simple programs (at least in IDEs). As soon as you start defining objects and classes inside **scala.App** Eclipse starts complaining about not finding the entry point of the program.

Try to fix this as follows:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object AkaObj {

  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    process()
  }

  def process() {
    // Create an Akka system
      val system = ActorSystem("PiSystem")

    // create the result listener, which will print the result and shutdown the system
      val listener = system.actorOf(Props[Listener], name = "listener")

    // create the master
      val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(listener)),
        name = "master")

    // start the calculation
      master ! Start
  }

  sealed trait PiMessage
  case class Work(value:String) extends PiMessage
  case class printComp(valu:String)extends PiMessage
  case object Start extends PiMessage 
  case class ListObj(cont:Seq[String]) extends PiMessage


  class Worker extends Actor{

    def receive()={

      case Work(value:String)=>
        println(value)
        sender ! printComp(value)
    }
  }

  class Master(listener: ActorRef) extends Actor{

    val nrOfWorkers = 10
    var counter = 0
    var lis = ListBuffer[String]()

    val workerRouter = context.actorOf(
    Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(nrOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

    def receive()={
      //handle message
      case Start=>workerRouter ! Work("Start now " + System.currentTimeMillis())
      case printComp(value:String)=> { 
        counter+=1
        lis.append(counter+"-"+value)
        if(counter >=10)
            listener ! ListObj(lis.toSeq)

        // Stops this actor and all its supervised children
        context.stop(self)
        }
    }
  }

  class Listener extends Actor{

    def receive()={

      case ListObj(cont:Seq[String])=>
        println("Completed " +cont)
        context.system.shutdown()
    }
  } 
}
```

Using `def main(args:Array[String])` fixes the problem in most cases.