# Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I was using Eclipse with java 7th version.

But recently, I have installed java 8th version. In cmd prompt, programs are working but not in eclipse. I have changed installed jre path in

`windows->preferences->java->installed JRE's`

This is the error I am getting:

`Error: Could not find or load main class`

Comment: Go "Window"->"Show View"->"Markers". Are there errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17355989/1031945

Comment: yes, errors are there

Comment: @MadhaviTalla solve them!

Comment: `Right click on project -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab -> double click listed JRE library -> select the appropriate JRE`

Comment: I have added appropriate JRE  only.

Comment: For new project its giving output with jre 1.7 libraries.

Comment: But for old it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `main` method is:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

}
```

In Eclipse, the error you had appears when you don't configure the launch method and you don't write down the `String [] args` part.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.

Comment: I am talking about Eclipse. You should read before systematically downvote answers.

Comment: You edited your answer after i vote down. Now it makes a little more sense, so i remove the vote-down.