# Eclipse debugging stopped working: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a Java project in Eclipse with several classes and a bunch of debug configs to test them. Up until today debugging was working fine. I just tried debugging one of the configs and got `Error: Could not find or load main class`. Same problem with the other configs. I also have an `ant` `build.xml` file that I run that exports a JAR. This JAR ran fine outside Eclipse with the class I wanted to debug. Read up on this [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334625/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) and tried a few things that were suggested there but none helped. Cleaned the project; checked that "java builder" is picked under project builders; checked `.classpath`. Nothing suspicious.

Trying to remember what happened between the last time I debugged and now. One thing stands out: out sysadmin rebooted my (RedHat) machine while I was working in Eclipse (thanks dude!). I did not see any error messages when I restarted Eclipse but could this have messed things up that can't be fixed by simply cleaning the project?

Whether or not that was the reason, what else can I check/try to get this to work again?

**UPDATE:** I found a way to get this to (sort of) work, but it feels more like a workaround rather than a solution since I still don't know what the problem is. What I did was I:

- Made a copy of my project dir (`cp -r Proj Proj2`)
- Deleted everything from `Proj2` except for `src/`, `lib/` and `build.xml`
- Created a new Java project in eclipse and pointed it to `Proj2`
- Also modified `Proj2/build.xml` to refer to `Proj2` instead of `Proj` -- this isn't really relevant to the original issue, but I am listing it for completeness

The result is that debugs work in `Proj2`, but they still don't in the original `Proj`

Comment: Try right-clicking on your server (in your servers window) and cleaning that, too, and the server's work directory (webapps directory). This sometimes works when nothing else does.

Comment: Try ./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState

Comment: Try disabling your anti-virus. Worked for me when the debugger just randomly wouldn't load.

Comment: If it is standard Java project in Eclipse, the classes are in bin folder, can you check, that you class is there ? I had o problem, that Eclipse was not able to delete the content of the folder and while failing on delete it was not compiling the code and so on...

Comment: @whistling_marmot Got `Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView` when I tried `Window->Show View->Other->Server->Servers`

Comment: @MohitSharma Started eclipse with that command, tried debugging, same result

Comment: @Betlista Hmm, weird. The `bin` dir seems to be unused: most `class` files are missing, the others are ancient, much older than when I was successfully debugging. Are my project settings out of whack?

Comment: Maybe you've lost your old server somehow, and you need to add a new server (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.). On a few occasions, I've ended up installing a new version of eclipse and pointing it to my existing workspace. Do your other projects still work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer based on my comment.

Check, whether `bin` is set as output folder:

[image: Eclipse Java project > Java Build Path > source tab]

if so and it seems "unused" - it might be, that Eclipse have some problem cleaning it - do the clean manually and try clean and rebuild (if you have "build automatically" set, just perform clean from eclipse) and check, that the classes are in bin...

[image: Eclipse: Project > Clean...]

Comment: by "do the clean manually" do you mean deleting all files and subdirs of `bin/`?

Comment: exited eclipse, deleted contents of `bin/`, started eclipse, cleaned project, checked that "build automatically" is on, also ran ant build. Then tried to debug: same result

Comment: @IZ Yes, by "do the clean manually" I meant delete on file system. After build, is content of your bin correct - as expected ?

Comment: I moved the existing `.log`, then restarted eclipse. There was a small number of messages including a couple that looked like errors/warnings. One was `!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.`, the other was `!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+CTRL+U:...` Neither looks relevant

Comment: Those are not relevant. Can you please answeralso whether there are classes in bin after rebuild ?

Comment: No, the `bin` folder is empty

Comment: Ok, but you have this one set as output folder, right? Do you have projects, your depends on? Try to close other project and rebuild manually = try to turn off-on automatic build and so on...