# (Error) Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, windows

I have been searching for this and nothing has helped, I'm trying to run the main class but keep getting an error. I am running this

```
java -classpath .\target\classes com.discordbot.Updated_Discord_Bot.Utils.Main
```

My main file is located in `MAIN_FOLDER\target\classes\com\discordbot\Updated_Discord_Bot/Utils/Main.class`

I have tried multiple commands and got nothing.

I want to run the main class located in `MAIN_FOLDER\target\classes\com\discordbot\Updated_Discord_Bot/Utils/Main.class` but keep getting this error, any help please?

Comment: Try `java -cp /target/classes com.discordbot.Updated_Discord_Bot.Utils.Main`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that would work if target was at the root level.

Comment: can you try `./target/classes` ?

Comment: Can you share your Main.java class's source code? at least your main method declaration? I suspect a typo in your signature of main method

Comment: @TimBiegeleise and Peter Nope that don't work iver and heres the Main https://pastebin.com/w8kYP4HA

Answer (score 1):

I tried `java -cp target\classes com.discordbot.Updated_Discord_Bot.Utils.Main` from Windows Command Line tool and standing on `MainFolder` in the CMD tool. The full path is like this

`MainFolder\target\classes\com\discordbot\Updated_Discord_Bot\Utils`

Where `MainFolder` is anywhere. All worked fine. What error do you get ? Are you sure all your .class files are generated ?

Comment: Im getting Error: Could not find or load main class and my class file are generated because I took it out of eclipse

Comment: hmm not sure how it doesn't see the main class. All I did different is is using `-cp` instead of `-classpath`. the .class file is in folder Utils and generated using `javac` command. Make sure of the folder names is same character case as the package (upper case and lower case).

Comment: Nope all the caps are perfect

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem but no success so far. Feel free to share anything new to help replicating the issue and I'll update if anything new got in my way.

Comment: You might want to check these questions  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334625/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean