# Error accessing checkboxes after putting them inside a scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I changed my xbl from just having checkboxes in the layout to them being in a scrollview. That way I can add more without troubling users with an options page. When I do this I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/T5hZHRxu

Here is the xml part that was changed:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scrollbox1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/num_input"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:background="#808080" />
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollbox1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/view1" >
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cb" />
        <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chex2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="@string/ac" />

  </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/aboutButt"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/aboutButt"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:background="#808080" />
```

Comment: What is at `MainActivity` line 111? Also, try cleaning your project

Comment: acBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chex2);

Comment: cleaning it worked. What does cleaning a project do, tidy up the XML?

Comment: You could say that. Posting an answer that may clarify a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when you change/add xml files and/or `Views` you will get this funny `ClassCastException` error. The editor just doesn't realize that they have been changed appropriately. Cleaning the project allows Eclipse to "sort through" the changes, I guess you could say. It rebuilds the project so Eclipse can "see" what is what and where everything is.

Basically, if you get a funny error like this, such as it saying it can't cast one `View` to another when you know you aren't trying to cast it, first thing to do is to clean the project

Project --> Clean --> Choose your project to clean

[Here is a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse) that may explain it better