# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Graph: method <init>()V not found

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, command-line

I'm getting a confusing error in eclipse but not on our main server from the command line linux account.  All code is in the main src directory, in eclipse.  Code compiles at command line but produces this error in Eclipse on my Mac OS X laptop:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Graph: method <init>()V not found
    at Lab17.main(Lab17.java:11)
```

**The code**

**Lab17.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab17 {

// Lab17 first attempt at creating a graph

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Graph myGraph = new Graph();

        URLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://csc.mendocino.edu/~jbergamini/222data/flights/flights");
            conn = url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open Flights file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String src = s.next();
            String dst = s.next();
            s.next();
            double cost = s.nextDouble();
            //System.out.println(src+" "+dst+" "+cost);
            myGraph.addEdge(src, dst, cost);
        }

        System.out.println(myGraph.breadthFirst("Austin", "Washington"));    
        System.out.println(myGraph.depthFirst("LosAngeles", "Washington"));
        System.out.println(myGraph.breadthFirst("LosAngeles", "Washington"));
        System.out.println(myGraph.depthFirst("Washington", "LosAngeles"));
        System.out.println(myGraph.breadthFirst("Washington", "LosAngeles"));

    }

}
```

**Graph.java**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Graph {

    private TreeMap<String, Vertex> vertexMap;

    /** Creates a new, empty graph */
    public Graph() {
        // create vertexMap for Graph
        vertexMap = new TreeMap<String, Vertex>();

    }

    /**
     * Adds an edge
     * @param src the source vertex
     * @param dst the destination vertex
     * @param cost the weight of the edge
     */
    public void addEdge(String src, String dst, double cost) {
        //System.out.println(src+" "+dst+" "+cost+" in Graph()");
        // check to see if there is a src vertex
        if(vertexMap.get(src) == null) {
            // if src Vertex does not exist create Vertex for src
            vertexMap.put(src, (new Vertex(src)));
            //System.out.println(vertexMap.get(src).toString());
        }

        // check to see if there is a dst Vertex
        if(vertexMap.get(dst) == null) {
            // if dst Vertex does not exist create Vertex for dst
            vertexMap.put(dst, (new Vertex(dst)));
            //System.out.println(vertexMap.get(dst).toString());
        }

        // populate the dst and cost for Edge on the src Vertex vertexMap element 
        Vertex srdVertex = vertexMap.get(src);
        Vertex dstVertex = vertexMap.get(dst);
        Edge sEdge = new Edge(dstVertex, cost);
        srdVertex.addEdge(sEdge);
    }

    /** Clears/empties the graph */
    public void clear() {
        vertexMap = new TreeMap<String,Vertex>();
    }

    /**
     * Traverses, depth-first, from src to dst, and prints the vertex names in the order visited.
     * @param src the source vertex
     * @param dst the destination vertex
     * @return whether a path exists from src to dst
     */
    public boolean depthFirst(String src, String dst) {
        System.out.println("Depth-first from "+src+" to "+dst);
        for(Map.Entry<String,Vertex> entry: vertexMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Vertex thisVertex = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(key + " => " + thisVertex.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Traverses, breadth-first, from src to dst, and prints the vertex names in the order visited
     * @param src the source vertex
     * @param dst the destination vertex
     * @return whether a path exists from src to dst
     */
    public boolean breadthFirst(String src, String dst) {
        System.out.println("Breadth-first from "+src+" to "+dst);
        // find starting vertex in vertexMap
        Vertex start = vertexMap.get(src);
        LinkedList<Vertex> vertexQue = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        LinkedList<Vertex> visitedV = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        // check it for null
        if( start == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(" Start vertex not found");
        }

        // create a Queue for searching through vertex edges
        //Queue<Vertex> q = new Queue<Vertex>();
        vertexQue.add( start );
        start.dest = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while( !vertexQue.isEmpty() && !found) {
            Vertex v = vertexQue.removeLast();
            if( v.toString() == dst) {
                // print queue
                found = true;
            }
            else if(!visitedV.contains(v)){
                // put all the adj vertex's into the queue
                for( Edge e: v.getEdges() ) {
                    Vertex w = e.getDst();
                    vertexQue.add( w );
                }
            }
            // add v to visitedV linked list

            if(!visitedV.contains(v)){
                visitedV.add(v);
            }
        }

        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i=0; i < visitedV.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(visitedV.get(i)+", ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");

        /*forVertex> entry: vertexMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Vertex thisVertex = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(key + " => " + thisVertex.toString());

            for(Edge e : thisVertex.getEdges() ){
                System.out.print(e.toString());
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("All Edges Evaluated");
        }*/
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Vertex.java**

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Vertex {

  private String name;
  private TreeSet<Edge> adj;
  public double dest;

  /**
   * Creates a new vertex
   * @param name the name of the vertex
   */
  public Vertex(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    adj = new TreeSet<Edge>();
  }

  public TreeSet<Edge> getEdges() {
      return this.adj;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the set of all edges starting from this vertex.
   * Set shall be ordered with respect to the names of the destination vertices.
   */
  public Set<Edge> allAdjacent() {
      Set<Edge> vertexSet = adj;

      return null;
  }

  public String toString() {

    return name;
  }

  public void addEdge(Edge e) {

      this.adj.add(e);
  }
}

public class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {

  private Vertex dst;
  private double cost;

  /** Creates a new edge with an associated cost
   * @param dst the destination vertex
   * @param cost the weight of the edge
   */
  public Edge(Vertex dst, double cost) {
    this.dst = dst;
    this.cost = cost;
  }

  public Vertex getDst() {
      return dst;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Edge o)
  {
      if(o == null)
          return -1;
      if(this == null)
          return -1;
      if( this.dst.toString().compareTo( ((Edge)o).dst.toString() ) == 0 )
          return 0;
      else if ( this.dst.toString().compareTo( ((Edge)o).dst.toString() ) < 0 )
          return 1;
      else 
          return -1;
  }

  public String toString() {
        String theEdgeS = this.dst.toString()+" "+Double.toString(cost);
        return theEdgeS;
      }
}
```

Not sure why Eclipse environment is treating the code differently than the command-line environment is.  The class's are a work in progress for a class.  I'm only trying to solve what seems like an Eclipse bug.

Comment: Can you tell us which line is line 11? Also, put the full stack trace. Why do you have a different exception in the title and in the question?

Comment: `Graph myGraph` where is `Graph` class in `Lab17`? You need to import it.

Comment: @Bill No need to import if you are in the same package.

Comment: @PradeepPati there is no package declaration in the code posted.

Comment: @Bill  exactly my point.

Comment: If there's no package definition then you're in the "default package".

Comment: If he's really getting an exception (which one?) then it's not a compile problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the eclipse has an old version of `Graph.class`.  You should try cleaning the project : See question [Function of Project > Clean in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

> Code compiles at command line but produces this error in Eclipse

Probable solutions :
1) Make sure the eclipse is using the same code as you use via command line.
2) Make a clean build inside eclipse because The case might be like it still referring the old class files regardless the thing that the source has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you're running, Graph.class is not found in the classpath.