# android:minSdkVersion & android:icon

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

Why is there error at android:minSdkVersion? And also how do I change the android:icon to default? I've tried android:icon="true" but it is wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.testing"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> //Error : <uses-sdk> tag should specify a  
  target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later versions, 
 compatibility behaviors may be enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?"    


<application android:icon="true" android:label="@string/app_name"> //Error : Boolean   
types not allowed (at 'icon' with value 'true'). 
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
              android:label="Login to your Account">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--  Entry for RegisterActivity.class -->
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
              android:label="Register New Account"></activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You should mention android:targetSdkVersion and For App Icon You Should mention any image from drawable folder. Like android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: @SubramanianR I've already change it to android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher". But then it states that **Should explicitly set android:allowBackup to true or false (it's true by default, and that can have some 
 security implications for the application's data)**

Comment: Its working fine for me. Can you please share your edited new manifest file.

Comment: "Should explicitly set android:allowBackup to true or false (it's true by default, and that can have some security implications for the application's data)" -- that is another attribute that Lint is suggesting that you should have on your `<application>` element.

Comment: @SubramanianR this is my new manifest file. I just added the android:targetSdkVersion and change android icon to drawable

     
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: @CommonsWare i dont really understand. Can you explain further?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `android-icon` will be drawable type as it will be an image. Its not a boolean.
2. Supply a target sdk version too
   e.g.,

   android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Answer (score 1):

```
android:icon=@drawable/ic_launcher
```

add this code to your uses-sdk

```
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

then go to project->clean->ok.

If that doesn't work it must have some internal error, to remove this follow the following steps:-

```
1.Delete the project.
2.Create new project.
```

Comment: I've changed everything just like you mentioned. However there are still warning. And after I clean the warning disappear. So does this mean that my coding is okay now? Because I'm new to this and I'm not really sure

Comment: Yes,coding is perfectly ok. Cleaning removes the .class files and recompiles the project. Basically, it forces a rebuild. For more clarity go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse