# What does "Project > Clean" do in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, project

What does **Project>Clean** do in **Eclipse**? Sometimes I have to do this to remove the compile time errors from the screen and other times I have to do this to get my code running without runtime errors.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/4549161/3326331](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4549161/3326331)

Answer (score 0):

It recompiles the project. Basically, it forces a rebuild.