# How is the maven build different from eclipse build?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have integrated m2e plugin.When i change the java file .It invokes building workspace. Is this is eclipse build or maven build.

And what exactly the difference between Eclipse clean and `mvn clean` ?

Comment: Aron ,Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The `m2e` plugin injects the Maven classpath into the Eclipse project plus it disables the default Eclipse resource copying so Maven can do it's magic (the Maven resource copy step can filter/transform resources).

The actual build for Java files uses the Eclipse compiler with the classpath supplied from m2e.

Clean: Unless you have configured something special, Eclipse clean will delete `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` while `mvn clean` will delete the whole `target/` folder.

Also, Eclipse will build the project again right after clean. For Maven, you need to issue another command (`mvn compile` or `mvn install`).

Comment: Suppose if a java file is changed .Is it mandatory to do mvn clean ,so that it would be reflected or eclipse clean is enough.?

Comment: If you have "Build automatically" enabled, you just need to save the Java file in Eclipse to compile it. No "clean" is necessary.

Comment: Can eclipse build generate WAR file like mvn build ?I am not sure about these things.

When i click on server add new resources to deploy in server.Is that mandatory that it should be a war file ?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't build a WAR. Instead the various plugins know how to deploy the files directly for a certain kind of server. If you want a WAR, read the documentation for the Maven WAR plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.project` file.

Do you have something like `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder` there? Then it's Maven build executed by Eclipse via `m2e`.

The exact difference between "Eclipse clean" and `mvn clean`...

`mvn clean` executes Maven clean phase, as it is configured (or inherited) in the `pom.xml`.

For Eclipse clean, see this question:

> [Function of Project > Clean in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks lexicore.
Does eclipse build generate war file.If no how we are able to deploy project and publish ?