# Why use project clean in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been working as a Java developer for just short of a year now and am gradually trying to increase my knowledge to speed up development times. One of the habits I find myself doing is forcing an occasional *clean* without really knowing if I need it.

I get that if you use it, your project will be completely re-built, however I don't fully understand under what circumstances I would want to use it.

If I understand correctly, most, if not all, changes to a project will be built automatically, so with that there should only be a rare occasion that I would actually need to use a project clean.

Comment: It removes all `.class` files and rebuilds the project.

Comment: This question may be a duplicate, check out here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse

Comment: It's not: that question is 'what', this question is 'why'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clean is useful if some external tool modifies your output folder. For example, you are using Eclipse, but occasinally compile via command line compiler into the same folder. In this case Eclipse may fail to do incremental build and display errors in code when they are actually absent.

Another case is working around some bug in Eclipse compiler itself. In very rare cases and in specific Eclipse versions/updates some classes which are necessary to be recompiled after specific code changes might be overlooked by compiler. If you were (un)happy enough to encounter such case, clean will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is for example useful if you delete a class, and then you forget to remove a reference to it in another class. If you do not clean the project, your local copy will still work, but what you actually did is that you just broke the build. ;)

Your local copy of the project will still work because the .class of the deleted class will still be there. To find out problems like this, is usually a good thing to compile the project from scratch on the integration system.

Comment: When I delete a Java file, Eclipse automatically deletes the class file for me. When did you see it keeping the class file? Do you have "Build automatically" enabled?

Comment: No, I have disabled it. ;)