# Eclipse Java running a file that no longer exist in my workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having a problem running a java file in my eclipse. I did check the class name of the file and that in main is the same. However, when ever I run the file, eclipse keep coming up with an error which says it can't find the file which i have already deleted. Any advice? Thank you

```
class PatientNames {
  void run() throws Exception {
// do not alter this method to avoid unnecessary errors with the automated judging
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)));
while (true) {
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
  int command = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  if (command == 0) // end of input
    break;
  else if (command == 1) // AddPatient
    AddPatient(st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
  else if (command == 2) // RemovePatient
    RemovePatient(st.nextToken());
  else // if (command == 3) // Query
    pr.println(Query(st.nextToken(), // START
                     st.nextToken(), // END
                     Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()))); // GENDER
}
pr.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// do not alter this method to avoid unnecessary errors with the automated judging
PatientNames ps2 = new PatientNames();
ps2.run();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the Class and the error you get to your question?

Comment: do a clean build of your project and try again

Comment: Have you already **cleaned** your project?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549161/function-of-project-clean-in-eclipse

Comment: Cleaned my project, but still having the problem

Comment: Try clearing your cache, too